How do i add Wheel Scrolling?
I have a project that converts MIDI inputs into keyboard actions, specifically optimized for Minecraft. However, I'm struggling with implementing a scrolling function. I've tried various solutions, but I'm not the best coder and could use some help.
Here's what I want to achieve:

When the MIDI input with ID 68 is pressed, it should scroll the mouse wheel up once, similar to scrolling one slot to the right in Minecraft.
When the MIDI input with ID 66 is pressed, it should scroll the mouse wheel down once.

Can anyone assist me with this?
Type: C# Windows Forms Application (.NET Framework)
.NET Version: 4.7.2
Form1.cs:
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Drawing.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using NAudio.Midi;
using WindowsInput;
using WindowsInput.Native;

namespace MidiConverter
{
    public partial class Form : System.Windows.Forms.Form
    {
        private MidiIn midiIn;
        private InputSimulator inputSimulator;
        private bool isWaitingForInput;

        public Form()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            inputSimulator = new InputSimulator();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            midiIn = new MidiIn(0);
            midiIn.MessageReceived += MidiIn_MessageReceived;
            midiIn.ErrorReceived += MidiIn_ErrorReceived;
            midiIn.Start();

            
        }

        private const int MOUSE_LEFT = 1;
        private const int MOUSE_RIGHT = 2;
        private const int MOUSE_UP = 3;
        private const int MOUSE_DOWN = 4;


        private bool isMouseMoving = false;
        private int currentMouseDirection = 0;

        private void MidiIn_MessageReceived(object sender, MidiInMessageEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.MidiEvent is NoteEvent midiEvent)
            {
                if (isWaitingForInput && midiEvent.CommandCode == MidiCommandCode.NoteOn)
                {
                    isWaitingForInput = false;
                    MessageBox.Show($"note: {midiEvent.NoteName}, id: {midiEvent.NoteNumber}");
                    return;
                }

                if (checkboxActive.Checked)
                {
                    var keyCode = GetVirtualKeyCode(midiEvent.NoteNumber);

                    if (midiEvent.CommandCode == MidiCommandCode.NoteOn)
                    {
                        if (keyCode.Item1)
                        {
                            StartMouseMove(keyCode.Item2);
                        }
                        else if (keyCode.Item2 == (int)VirtualKeyCode.LBUTTON || keyCode.Item2 == (int)VirtualKeyCode.RBUTTON)
                        {
                            MouseDown((VirtualKeyCode)keyCode.Item2);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            inputSimulator.Keyboard.KeyDown((VirtualKeyCode)keyCode.Item2);
                        }
                    }
                    else if (midiEvent.CommandCode == MidiCommandCode.NoteOff)
                    {
                        if (keyCode.Item1)
                        {
                            StopMouseMove();
                        }
                        else if (keyCode.Item2 == (int)VirtualKeyCode.LBUTTON || keyCode.Item2 == (int)VirtualKeyCode.RBUTTON)
                        {
                            MouseUp((VirtualKeyCode)keyCode.Item2);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            inputSimulator.Keyboard.KeyUp((VirtualKeyCode)keyCode.Item2);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private (bool, int) GetVirtualKeyCode(int noteNumber)
        {
            switch (noteNumber)
            {
                case 48: // C4
                    return (false, (int)VirtualKeyCode.SHIFT);
                case 49: // C#4
                    return (false, (int)VirtualKeyCode.VK_Q);
                case 50: // D4
                    return (false, (int)VirtualKeyCode.VK_A);
                case 51: // D#4
                    return (false, (int)VirtualKeyCode.VK_W);
                case 52: // E4
                    return (false, (int)VirtualKeyCode.VK_S);
                case 53: // F4
                    return (false, (int)VirtualKeyCode.VK_D);
                case 54: // F#4
                    return (false, (int)VirtualKeyCode.VK_E);
                case 55: // G4
                    return (false, (int)VirtualKeyCode.SPACE);
                case 56: // G#4
                    return (false, (int)VirtualKeyCode.F5);
                case 57: // A4
                    return (false, (int)VirtualKeyCode.VK_F);
                case 60: // C5
                    return (false, (int)VirtualKeyCode.LBUTTON);
                case 61: // C#5
                    return (false, (int)VirtualKeyCode.RBUTTON);
                case 62: // D5
                    return (true, MOUSE_LEFT);
                case 63: // D#5
                    return (true, MOUSE_UP);
                case 64: // E5
                    return (true, MOUSE_DOWN);
                case 65: // F5
                    return (true, MOUSE_RIGHT);
                //scrolling:
                // G#5:68 up wheel_scrolling once
                // F#5:66 down wheel_scrolling once
                default:
                    return (false, (int)VirtualKeyCode.ESCAPE);
            }
        }

        private new void MouseDown(VirtualKeyCode button)
        {
            switch (button)
            {
                case VirtualKeyCode.LBUTTON:
                    inputSimulator.Mouse.LeftButtonDown();
                    break;
                case VirtualKeyCode.RBUTTON:
                    inputSimulator.Mouse.RightButtonDown();
                    break;
            }
        }

        private new void MouseUp(VirtualKeyCode button)
        {
            switch (button)
            {
                case VirtualKeyCode.LBUTTON:
                    inputSimulator.Mouse.LeftButtonUp();
                    break;
                case VirtualKeyCode.RBUTTON:
                    inputSimulator.Mouse.RightButtonUp();
                    break;
            }
        }

        private void StartMouseMove(int direction)
        {
            if (!isMouseMoving)
            {
                isMouseMoving = true;
                currentMouseDirection = direction;
                MoveMouseContinuously();
            }
        }

        private void StopMouseMove()
        {
            isMouseMoving = false;
        }

        private async void MoveMouseContinuously()
        {
            const int moveAmount = 20;
            while (isMouseMoving)
            {
                switch (currentMouseDirection)
                {
                    case MOUSE_LEFT:
                        inputSimulator.Mouse.MoveMouseBy(-moveAmount, 0);
                        break;
                    case MOUSE_UP:
                        inputSimulator.Mouse.MoveMouseBy(0, -moveAmount);
                        break;
                    case MOUSE_DOWN:
                        inputSimulator.Mouse.MoveMouseBy(0, moveAmount);
                        break;
                    case MOUSE_RIGHT:
                        inputSimulator.Mouse.MoveMouseBy(moveAmount, 0);
                        break;
                }
                await Task.Delay(10);
            }
        }

        private void MidiIn_ErrorReceived(object sender, MidiInMessageEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show($"error: {e.RawMessage}");
        }

        private void check_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            isWaitingForInput = true;
        }

        private void checkBox2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (checkBox2.Checked)
            {
                this.TopMost = true;
            }
            else
            {
                this.TopMost = false;
            }
        }

        private void checkBox3_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (checkBox3.Checked)
            { 
                this.AutoSize = true; 
            }
            else { 
                this.AutoSize = false; 
            }
        }

        private void linkLabel1_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("https://snoopti.de/discord");
        }

        private void linkLabel2_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("https://snoopti.de/github");
        }

        private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Image image = MidiCraft.Properties.Resources.keybinds;

            string tempFilePath = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "midicraft-keybinds_temp.png");
            image.Save(tempFilePath, ImageFormat.Png);

            Process.Start(tempFilePath);
        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}

I've tried various solutions

https://github.com/michaelnoonan/inputsimulator/blob/a61df64303cb76b005a3ced19eae4cb4755e2e42/WindowsInput/MouseSimulator.cs#L232

You should elaborate on what and why you are scrolling. Trying to "simulate" a mouse may not be the best solution in this case.
